# GeoMesa Accumulo ingest via Oracle JDBC failed

Tags: oracle-spatial, geomesa, jdbc

I tried to ingest data from Oracle 12c into GeoMesa 2.2.1 (with Accumulo 1.9.2, using docker from geodocker).
Java version 1.8, and I use ojdbc8.jar for JDBC driver.

My oracle table CUSTOMERS have 3 string field:

```
UID VARCHAR2(36)
NAME VARCHAR2(100)
CITY VARCHAR2(100)
```

I use this customers.sft:

```
geomesa = {
  sfts = {
    customers = {
      attributes = [
        { name = "UID",     type = "String" , index = true },
        { name = "NAME",    type = "String" },
        { name = "CITY",    type = "Integer" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and this customers.conf:

```
geomesa.converters.customers  = {
  type       = "jdbc",
  connection = "jdbc:oracle:thin:myuser/mypassword@//192.168.1.11:1521/MYDB"
  id-field   = "$1",
  fields = [
    { name = "UID",     type = "string", transform = "$1" },
    { name = "NAME",    type = "string", transform = "$2" },
    { name = "CITY",    type = "string", transform = "$3" }
  ]
}
```

with this command to ingest:

```
echo "SELECT UID, NAME, CITY FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ROWNUM < 20"  | geomesa-accumulo ingest -u user -p password -c customers -s customers.sft -C customers.conf
```

Ingesting failed with log said:

```
2023-06-15 21:59:17,718 WARN  [org.locationtech.geomesa.convert.jdbc.JdbcConverter] Failed parsing input:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:223)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:56)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CCallableStatement.java:744)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeInternal(T4CCallableStatement.java:1300)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.convert.jdbc.JdbcConverter$StatementIterator.hasNext(JdbcConverter.scala:62)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.convert2.AbstractConverter$ErrorHandlingIterator.liftedTree1$1(AbstractConverter.scala:170)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.convert2.AbstractConverter$ErrorHandlingIterator.hasNext(AbstractConverter.scala:169)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.collection.CloseableIterator$$anon$5.hasNext(CloseableIterator.scala:92)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.AbstractIngest$LocalIngestWorker$1.run(AbstractIngest.scala:119)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 54, Sql = SELECT UID, NAME, CITY FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ROWNUM < 2;, OriginalSql = SELECT UID, NAME, CITY FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
        ... 24 more
2023-06-15 21:59:18,219 INFO  [org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.user] Local ingestion complete in 00:00:01
2023-06-15 21:59:18,219 INFO  [org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.user] Ingested 0 features and failed to ingest 1 feature for file: <stdin>..
```

Any insight what I've done wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to FINEST, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file. That should then show you the actual Query that is sent to Oracle

Comment: Thanks Ian, I added additional info from log file.

Comment: Solved by adding sql comment (--) after my SQL statement

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this:

```
Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 54, Sql = SELECT UID, NAME, CITY FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ROWNUM < 2;, OriginalSql = SELECT UID, NAME, CITY FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
```

The error is reported on the last character of the statement, i.e. the `;`

It looks like accumulo decided to add a `;` at the end of the statement. It should not do that the `;` is NOT part of the SQL language. It is a convention for terminating SQL statements, typically for command-line tools that take SQL statements as input, like Oracle's `sqlplus` or `sqlCL` tools.

Unless there is a mistake on your side, and what you wrote is really this:

```
echo "SELECT UID, NAME, CITY FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ROWNUM < 20;"  | geomesa-accumulo ingest -u user -p password -c customers -s customers.sft -C customers.conf
```

But if you really wrote what you showed, i.e. without `;` then the problem is in accumulo, which would be odd, since it would then not work at all. Maybe it has an option to automatically add a `;` after each statement, that you need to turn off ...

Comment: Thanks Albert for the insight.

I can successfully ingest the data with adding sql comment (--) after my statement, so anything added after that (including semicolon) will be ignored.

My ingest command above become:

echo "SELECT UID, NAME, CITY FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ROWNUM < 20 --"  | geomesa-accumulo ingest -u user -p password -c customers -s customers.sft -C customers.conf

Comment: Clever workaround!

Comment: Still, if accumulo always appends a semi-colon after each statement, then it cannot possibly work.